# Solving a series RLC DC step response circuit

Tags: passive-networks, step-response

[image]

I got two different answers to this RLC problem when using a method shown in class. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I graphed each answer. I'm assuming the answer for Vc on the right is correct, as the response looks nromal, but I still don't know why my diff.eq. method is wrong.

Comment: I(L) goes from 30V/4R to 0 A with  a known RLC response using fo and Q

Answer (score 0):

Well, we have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGsjUI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using KCL, we can write (I'm doing the analysis in the s-domain):

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_{\text{R}_1}=\text{I}_{\text{R}_3}+\text{I}_\text{C}\\
\\
\text{I}_{\text{R}_2}+\text{I}_{\text{R}_3}+\text{I}_2=0\\
\\
\text{I}_1=\text{I}_{\text{R}_1}+\text{I}_{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{C}=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_2
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

Using KVL, we can write:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_{\text{R}_2}=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_{\text{R}_3}=\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_4}{\text{sL}}\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{C}=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\left(\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\right)}=\text{V}_3\text{sC}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Using your given values we get:

$$\text{i}\left(t\right)=-\text{i}_2\left(t\right)=-\mathcal{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[-\frac{10\left(12+\text{s}\right)}{\text{s}\left(\text{s}+4\right)^2}\right]_{\left(t\right)}=\frac{5\left(3-\exp\left(-4t\right)\left(3+8t\right)\right)}{2}\tag3$$